# How can I prevent rerendering of a pure component with pure children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, memoization

I have a functional React component in which I use `React.memo` to prevent unnecessary rerenders. If it contains  only a string as a child, it is only rendered only when the string is changed (as expected). However, When I add another child component which also uses `React.memo`, it is always rerendered (even when child component is not rerendered). Here is a sample code indicating those cases:

```
const Parent = React.memo(() => <div> Parent </div>) // Rendered only once!
```

Second Case:

```
const Child = React.memo(() => <div> Child </div>); // Rendered only once!
const Parent = React.memo(() => <Child />); // Rerendered everytime
```

To be more clear, the Parent is always rerendered (as if `React.memo` is not used) in the second case. Obviously, there is no need to rerender it as its child does not rerender and thus none of Parent's children is changed. Is there something I am missing? How can I change my implementation to avoid rerendering of `Parent` component?

Comment: Your Second case is supposed to work, at least it does for me. Memoization is not controlled by the inside of the function, but by the outside. It uses the props. So might it be that your simplified case does not contain outer factors that cause the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: The code you posted does not demonstrate the behaviour you describe, it depends how `Parent` is rendered, please provide a minimal reproducible example.